# Azure active directory v2.0 query for Web API integration on a SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

We have a SharePoint publishing site with anonymous access hosted on the internet. As per out latest requirements, we need to implement user login (AzureAD, Microsoft personal and work accounts, and more).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-flows

As per the documentation here, we want to implement this using Web API to get the secure information from the database.  We are thinking about using MSAL.js file for user login and logout on the SharePoint and after getting a bearer token we can call the Web API for the additional data from our database.

Standalone Web APIs restriction:  “You can use the v2.0 endpoint to build a Web API that is secured with OAuth 2.0. However, that Web API can receive tokens only from an application that has the same Application ID. You cannot access a Web API from a client that has a different Application ID. The client won't be able to request or obtain permissions to your Web API.”

How can we create two applications with same application ID at [App Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/)? Or should we use the same application ID at SharePoint and Web API’s end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to register two application, you only need to one register application. After you register the application, you can using the MSAL library below to get the token to call the web API:

```
<script class="pre">
    var userAgentApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication("e5e5f2d3-4f6a-461d-b515-efd11d50c338", null, function (errorDes, token, error, tokenType) {
        // this callback is called after loginRedirect OR acquireTokenRedirect (not used for loginPopup/aquireTokenPopup)
    })
    userAgentApplication.loginPopup(["user.read"]).then(function (token) {
        var user = userAgentApplication.getUser();
        console.log(token);
        // signin successful
    }, function (error) {
        // handle error
    });
</script>
```

And to protect the web API, you can use the same app and refer the code below:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{ 
    var tvps = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        // The web app and the service are sharing the same clientId
        ValidAudience = "e5e5f2d3-4f6a-461d-b515-efd11d50c338",
        ValidateIssuer = false,
    };

    // NOTE: The usual WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticaitonMiddleware uses a
    // metadata endpoint which is not supported by the v2.0 endpoint.  Instead, this 
    // OpenIdConenctCachingSecurityTokenProvider can be used to fetch & use the OpenIdConnect
    // metadata document.

    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(tvps, new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration")),
    });
}
```